# Best way to make a contained array's elements accessible but immutable outside containing class

Tags: c#, properties

If I have a class like this:

```
public class ArrayContainer
{
    public int[] Array { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public ArrayContainer()
    {
        Array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Value = 10;
    }
}
```

This assures that `Value` will not be able to be changed outside the `ArrayContainer` class, but individual `Array` values will be able to be changed. What is the easiest workaround to this to assure that you can view values in `Array`, but not change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose it as a read-only collection by using [`Array.AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b.aspx).

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<int> MyArray { get; private set; }

MyArray = Array.AsReadOnly(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet would be to define your own `ImmutableArray` class, which implements an indexer that has no setter. The getter would delegate to the indexer of your `Array` member, which would be passed as a constructor parameter. Make `Array` private then, and expose an instance of your `ImmutableArray` class.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [readonlycollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) which you could create and pass out to users of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a read-only wrapper for collections in the base class library. It's the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

If I remember correctly, the compiler complains if you try to access the `set` accessor.